# 1 x Magento 2.2.x multistore multidomains not working

Tags: magento2

I have a problem with setting up a properly working multistore and multidomains.
I want to make:
- one store on 2-3 different domains with different layouts (the same assortment), 
- second store on a 1 different domain (with a completely different assortment).

I have installed Magento on one domain - domain2.biz, and stores look like this:

WEBSITE   /   STORE   /   STORE VIEW

domain1     domain1.com     domain1_view

domain1     domain2.biz     domain2_view

domain3     domain3.net     domain3_view

I added to the index.php file:

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {

   case 'domain2.biz':
   case 'www.domain2.biz':
      $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'domain1';
      $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
   break;

   case 'domain1.com':
   case 'www.domain1.com':
      $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'domain1';
      $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
   break;

   case 'domain3.net':
   case 'www.domain3.net':
      $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'domain3';
      $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
   break;
}
```

and the .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain3\.net MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain3
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain3\.net MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain3\.net MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain3
SetEnvIf Host ^domain3\.net MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain3\.net [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:domain3]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain3\.net [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]

SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.biz MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.biz MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.biz MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.biz MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain2\.biz [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:domain1]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain2\.biz [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]

SetEnvIf Host www\.domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:domain1]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

Unfortunately, the only working store is the one on whose domain Magento has been installed (domain2.biz).
Should I upload some files for the other two domains? Additional domains are not configured (they do not have any files).
What file should be there and what should it contain?

Is it possible that it works ONLY with virtual hosts?

Comment: I never did this on my own, but this looks like the wrong approach.I would suggest reading the docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

Comment: I'm sure that the redirection above is incorrect. Unfortunately, I don't know what should be appropriate. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can set the base urls for each store view in the admin console in configuration/web and as you have two stores on one website use the store MAGE_RUN_TYPE instead of website but you may not need to alter the htaccess file (that depends on your setup).